# How would I insert a table row using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hey Angular Wizards...

I'm working on a project with Angular version 4.0.0

I have the following structure in my app-component template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Label</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
      <tr app-vcr [item]="item"></tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the app-vcr template:

```
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
<td>{{item.label}}</td>
<td><button (click)="viewDetails()">Details</button></td>
```

I have another app-vcr-details component with the following template:

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="99">
  <div>
   {{item.details}}
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

In the app-vcr component, I implement the viewDetails() method with this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, Input, Injector,ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

import { VcrDetailsComponent } from 'components/VcrDetailsComponent';

...

constructor(
 private elem:ViewContainerRef,
 private r: ComponentFactoryResolver
) {}

viewDetails(){
 let factory = this.r.resolveComponentFactory(VcrDetailsComponent);
 this.elem.createComponent(factory)
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that when I click the view details button, it inserts the details component but it inserts it like this:

```
<app-vcr-details> <--- ** this gets inserted, which is breaking the table **
 <tr>
  <td colspan="99">
    <div>
      Show the item details here!
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</app-vcr-details>
```

I've also tried changing the selector for the app-vcr-details to be an attribute selector, but then I get this:

```
<div> <--- ** this gets inserted, which is also breaking the table **
 <tr>
  <td colspan="99">
    <div>
      Show the item details here!
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</div>
```

How can I insert the details table row the correct way?

Thanks you.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest instead of having a component for the table-row, have a component for the entire table.